# How to model time series with unevenly spaced observations?

Tags: r, time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have three time series of the following form:

$T = T_{2000}, T_{2004}, T_{2008}, …$

$U = U_{1998}, U_{1999}, U_{2000}, U_{2001}, U_{2002}, U_{2003}, …$

$V = V_{1998}, V_{1999}, V_{2000}, V_{2001}, V_{2002}, V_{2003}, …$

I would like to predict $T$ from $U + V$, but since the time series have unequal numbers of observations ($T$ has four times less data points: the series 'coincide' only every four years), I am unsure of how to go with it.

Any help (and software recommendations, preferably with R) would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The biggest mistake that people make with time series forecasting problems is [look-ahead bias](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lookaheadbias.asp#:%7E:text=What%20Is%20the%20Look%2DAhead,in%20the%20study%20or%20simulation.).

To avoid this bias, it's vital to make explicit a) the date *at* which we make predictions and b) the date *for* which we make predictions.

Our model should be capable of incorporating all information available at (or before) the date *at* which we make predictions.

So you want to make predictions for $T$ which occurs at 4 year intervals. But when do you want to make the predictions?

1. Do you make a prediction each time a new value of $U$ or $V$ comes in? So, in 2000 you make a 4 year ahead prediction, in 2001 you make a 3 year ahead prediction and so on?
2. Or do you just want to make predictions every 4 years? In which case your problem is about how to bake the historical values of $U$ and $V$ in to your features.
3. Or maybe you don't want to forecast the future at all and instead want to try and generate a same time 'nowcast' of $T$.

I suspect from your phrasing that you are looking at option 2.

In this case we can engineer features from $U$ and $V$ that include some history. As a few examples:

- Exponentially weighted moving average
- Rolling Average
- Rolling Z-score
- Rolling Standard Deviation
- Min/Max values from window

The python package [tsfresh](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/list_of_features.html) has good documentation on feature engineering transforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use U & V as features what you can do is have rows equal to the number of T observations and since T has a frequency of 4 years hence have 8 features equal to the last 4 years (compared to the year you are predicting) observation of U & V each.

As an example to predict T(2004) use U(2000-2003) & V(2000-2003) as features.

This is just one such way. It might also be that your prediction of U(2008) is dependant on V(1998 ~ 2007). In such case, you might want to model using the past value of T as well since it might capture well the previous values of U & V ( for years >4 )

Comment: So I should just use lags of (T, U, V)? What kind of model is that? AR(x)?

Comment: You will have to check which model works, but Arima etc should work nicely. But I was talking about creating a dataset/features. It makes sense that to predict T(2004) you can only use U < 2004 & V < 2004.

Comment: Alright. I'll wait a bit for additional suggestions, but will start looking into ARIMA straight away.